# How to force implementation of a nested abstract class in an abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, class, nested, abstract

I'm new to Java but used to OOP programming. Is there a way I can force implementing an abstract class nested into another abstract class like in the code below :

```
public abstract class A
{

    public abstract class B extends C
    {
        @Override
        public abstract void foo();

    }

}
```

I would like B to be implemented in each subclass of A. Is it possible?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: You want to enforce that every subclass of A contains a nested class that implements B? It is not possible by pure Java means.

Comment: Are you saying that you want each sub-class of A to also be a subclass of B or to CONTAIN a sub-class of B?

Comment: FYI, I believe the real solution here is to have A extend C. If subclasses of A choose to implement C via another subclass, that is the choice of the subclass.

Answer (score 6):

If I read your question correctly, where you want each sub-class of A to CONTAIN a subclass of B, there is not a direct way to do this. However, you could do something like the below:

```
public abstract class A
{

  public abstract class B extends C
  {
      @Override
      public abstract void foo();
   }

   protected abstract B getBInstance();
}
```

Because this forces sub-class of A to return an instance of B, they must have access to some sub-class of B.

However, you should really ask yourself why A should care about its sub-classes implementing B unless A uses B in some way which would require the above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, make `B` an interface, as shown in [*When an Abstract Class Implements an Interface*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. You can perfectly well extend A to a concrete class whether B is an abstract class, an interface, or whatever.

Comment: Good point, but I understood the question to be about how to defer the implementation of `foo()` when deriving from `A` in a way that the compiler can enforce. Otherwise, it does not seem possible. Naturally, I'd welcome a counter-example.

Comment: I believe my answer provides a possibility. I am not saying it is good design but it would enforce that each subclass of A has ACCESS to a subclass of B.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The A class should only provide what behaviour an instance of A has (either through the abstract or implemented methods). It should not state anything about how A is implemented.

It's not even clear how this would be useful either since you could not call the implemented class B so it would need to be named something else meaning it's existence could be ignored.